# How to concatenate strings into one string in Java?

Tags: java, string, list

I have a list that contains three objects:
Object1, Object2, Object 3.

When I call the toString method for each object this is the result:

Letter of the object: A;   Number of the object: 1.

Letter of the object: B;   Number of the object: 2.

Letter of the object: C;   Number of the object: 3.

So what I want this method to do is put all of that information in a String.
So my method is:

```
public String method1 () {
  //And here is where its supposed to do that stuff
}
```

I know how to take a list and go through it so I can cast the `toString` in each and every one of the objects that's inside my list, but what I don't know how to do is how to put all of this `toString` information of all the objects that are on my list on a single String variable, so my method returns a string with all of that information.

Comment: Have you tried calling `.toString()` on the list itself?

Comment: [Java String concatenation: How to combine (merge) two Strings](https://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/java/combine-two-strings). You will need a way to do it with more than two strings, for example using a loop or a stream.

Comment: My guess is that the downvotes your question has received are for lack of demonstration of effort, in particular search effort. I’m more in doubt about the upvote; it might be because this question could be useful for others because your situation is pretty common.

Comment: @OleV.V. the link you gave in your comment in not very helpful. It recommends using StringBuffer instead of StringBuilder, suggesting it was written back in 200x before we had StringBuilder. Also, it incorrectly says that using StringBuffer is more efficient when adding a lot of strings: this is only correct when doing so in a loop.

Comment: Correct, @DodgyCodeException. I’m sure a search can turn up more helpful links. There’s no problem in using `StringBuffer`, though. It’s said that it incurs a synchronization overhead, but when used inside a method, modern Java versions are smart enough to eliminate that.

Comment: @OleV.V. thanks for the reply. I found it interesting that modern Java compilers (presumably JIT?) eliminate the synchronization overhead of using StringBuffer. Have you got any links to more information on that?

Comment: @DodgyCodeException “StringBuilder is now obsolete, after just one Java version. The benefit we had with StringBuilder was as an unsynchronized version of StringBuffer. However, with lock eliding we should not need to concern ourselves with this anymore.” [JavaSpecialists' Newsletter issue 179](https://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue179.html) (December 2009)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185440/discussion-between-ole-v-v-and-dodgycodeexception).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to Java, I'm not feeling so good!

You correctly assumed, that you need to call the toString()-Method of your objects (sequentially). You have several options of doing so:

```
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
for (Object obj : list) {
   result.append(obj.toString());
}
return result.toString();
```

The above is among the "easiest" ones. However there are several others (in case you want to insert a divider, for example).

```
return list.stream()
        .map(Object::toString)
        .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
```

is shorter and also valid (and will comma-separate your individual Strings).

DodgyCodeException also mentioned calling `list.toString()`. This is useful for debugging or logging purposes, but gives less control over the final output.

Comment: Or just call `list.toString()` ;-)

Comment: While this does create a String containing all "toStrings" of the contained objects, it also adds a wrapper, and does it's own separator. Other than for debugging or logging, using toString() on a list is usually not the right way.